# How to get the custom font

Tags: html, css, fonts

This [link](https://zee.vn/about/) uses a custom font called zee family. How do I save the rendered font from this website(zee family), any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the network tab in your browser's developer tools. You can filter by fonts, and then open/save the font file from there

Comment: If you're using a Chrome based browser, you can go to the "network" tab in the developer tools, and filter on "font", edit beaten

Comment: or you may find the corresponding `@font-face` ([on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)) on the page source , mapping the typeface file to a font family name. There are some tricks through the web developer tools both on firefox and chrome but it's really that simple. If you want to use that same font just include the same exact font face declaration and bind it to the same file but self hosted

Answer (score 1):

After opening Developer Tools <kbd>F12</kbd>, find the Inspector tab. Click on any page element that used the font in question, like `<body>`

This will display a list of styles in the middle pane, and the very first one probably says `post-6.css` or some CSS file. Click on this file name, and this will show the contents of the CSS -- in this case, there will be a list of URLs where you can download the WOFF and TTF files.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

> @font-face
>
> The @font-face CSS at-rule specifies a custom font with which to
> display text; the font can be loaded from either a remote server or a
> locally-installed font on the user's own computer.

If you wish to enumerate all the available `@font-face` definitions loaded by any current page, just run the following snippet in the js console:

```js
[...document.styleSheets]
  //for each stylesheet in the document
  .forEach((stylesheet) => {
    try {
      [...stylesheet.cssRules]
      //for each css rule in the current stylesheet
        .forEach((rule) => {
          //if the rule matches a fontface definition
          if (rule instanceof CSSFontFaceRule || rule.type === CSSRule.FONT_FACE_RULE) {
            //logs the css rule as is
            console.log(rule.cssText);
          }
        });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('ERROR: ', e);
    }
  });
```

It will echo every single font-face definition where each one has a `font-family` key and a list of urls with the corresponding font files.

Consider that the `src` property allows multiple sources that will be evaluated in the order found and the first one being available and supported will be used by the browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/src

> src
>
> The src CSS descriptor for the @font-face at-rule specifies the
> resource containing font data. It is required for the @font-face rule
> to be valid.

**Easier approach...**

In case you are more comfortable using a solution more straight to the point (but showing less details), the Firefox browser has a feature showing all the font files used by the page inside the Developer Tools.

I show here the way to access to that panel (I use the italian language but it's easy to find out):

[image]